# Show that if $F$ is a field, then $<x>$ is maximal in $F[x]$. Also, show that $F[x]$ is not local.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

See statement above. So far I have the following:

Assume that $<x>$ is not maximal. Then $ <x> \subset <f(x)> \neq F[x]$.

This means that $x = f(x) g(x)$. Since $x$ is irreducible, then this is a contradiction, meaning that $<x>$ is maximal.

I feel like this is too simple or I'm simply misunderstanding something. I also have no clue how to show that $F[x]$ is not local.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sufficient. In fact, if $F$ is a field, there is a one to one correspondence between irreducible polynomials $f(x)\in F[x]$ and maximal ideals.

Additionally, note that
$F[x]/\langle x\rangle \cong F$, so that the quotient is a field. Thus, $\langle x\rangle$ is maximal.

Answer (score 1):

A local ring has a unique maximal ideal. Can you find another maximal ideal in $F[x]$?

Comment: I would assume there is another one, otherwise we wouldn't be asked to show it isn't local haha. Are monic polynomials maximal?

Comment: Not if they're reducible.

Comment: Oh right, like $x^2 = x.x$. Could you give me some direction as to how to find another maximal ideal?

Comment: Can you find another irreducible polynomial?

Comment: I want to say that $x+p$ is irreducible, but I'm not so sure since the char($F$) is either 0 or $p$. (here $p$ is prime).

Comment: Nvm. The root is $-p$ which is in $F$ i think.

Comment: What if you try $p=1$?